# Check if image is already stored using Parse

Tags: objective-c, caching, parse-platform

I have image data that I'm retrieving from the Parse database, but I'm not sure if the app is using the internet connection every time to retrieve the images when there's a cached copy in the device. When I turn off wifi the images still load, so I know that there is a cached copy, but how do I change my code or add code to make sure that my app checks to see if a cached file is being stored before attempting to communicate to the database?

This is my code:

```
PFUser * current = [PFUser currentUser];
name = current[@"name"];
PFFile * image = current[@"image"];

//how to check if a cached copy exists before executed this code?
[image getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
    if (!error) {
        setImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    }
}];
```